# ASP.Net Core2 Razor Selectlist

Tags: razor-pages

It seems that there is ZERO documentation related to a select/dropdown list in ASP.NET Core2 with **Razor Pages**.

I would like to create dropdown lists that select/display data from another table.

I am suspecting that each 'view' (Index, Details, Create and Edit) will most likely need a different implementation? 
For example:
the Index and Details (which are View only) page, would need to read the value in the field, but then fetch that associated text from the reference table.

There is a ton of info out there that relates to an MVC but Razor pages don't have a ViewBag.

I have tried adding

var school = _context.AdmSchool.ToList();
SelectList selectList = new SelectList(school, "AdmSchoolId", "AdmSchoolName", null);
school = selectList;

in the create.cshtml.cs ('controller' for want of a Razor name) file

and

```
@Html.DropDownList("school", null, null, htmlAttributes: new{@class="form-control", placeholder="Select School"});
```

into the Create.cshtml (view) file.

So does anybody out there have experience with Razor pages?
I must confess that I am an absolute newbie, so the more verbose your response, the more I am likely to understand it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking to use the [select tag helper in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/select-tag-helper) instead of the old-style Html helpers from earlier versions of MVC.

The data for the `asp-items` attribute should be a `List<SelectListItem>`:

```
var items = _context.AdmSchool.Select(s => new SelectListItem{
                                Value = s.AdmSchoolId.ToString(), 
                                Text = s.AdmSchoolName
                                }).ToList();
```

You can assign this to a property on your PageModel (controller) or to ViewData (not ViewBag):

```
ViewData["Items"] = items;
```

Then you assign that to the asp-items attribute:

```
<select asp-for="SelectedAdmSchoolId" asp-items="@((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Items"])"></select>
```

Finally, add a property to the PageModel to capture the selected value:

```
[BindProperty]
public int SelectedAdmSchoolId {get; set;}
```